# How to implement D3.js v4 multiple separate charts on single html page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement multiple separate D3.js v4 charts (i.e. bar charts and line chart) on one html page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new SVG or Canvas element for each chart, but give each one a unique ID. Create a different base selection for each of these charts.

For example:

```
var barChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'bar-chart');

var lineChart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'line-chart');
```

Now you can use `barChart` as your base selection for the bar chart code, and `lineChart` as your base selection for your line chart code.

Comment: Hi Wes, 
I am using different SVG elements for both charts and getting this error: 'Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,116LNaN,117L…"' when I comments one chart code then it work for other, same happens for other chart. do you have idea what I am missing here.

Comment: No idea, we would need to see your code. Follow the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (eg, cut your code down to the simplest, clearest version possible) and create a new question about the error.